# Select/Case in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to have crystal reports run through a Select statement however I keeps on dropping out after hitting the first match instead of continuing on through each case. How can I get it to evaluate each condition on it's own merits instead of it automaticaly breaking after finding the first match?

Example

```
  local numbervar varNumber := 0; 
    Select 7
      case is <= 1:
         varNumber := varNumber + 1   //Only gets to here
      case is <= 2:
         varNumber := varNumber + 1
      case is <= 3:
         varNumber := varNumber + 1
      case is <= 4:
         varNumber := varNumber + 1
      case is <= 5:
         varNumber := varNumber + 1
      case is <= 6:
         varNumber := varNumber + 1
      case is <= 7:
         varNumber := varNumber + 1
   End Select
```

varNumber value should be 7 by the end of the select statement as each condition should have evaluated true, however it stops after hitting the first case, resulting in varNumber being 1, normally you would have a break statement to tell it to stop falling through each case statement, but this isn't happening.

Alternatively is there a way to simulate this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using `select case` if you wanted to do this you would have to construct multiple `If` statements or possibly a `loop`.

What is the purpose of this?  I'm not sure I see the point of the function - as it appears to return 7 all the time?

Comment: It was an oversimplified example to highlight the specific problem. The 'select' statement won't always select 7, it will be a variable. It's purpose is to assign values based on the input variable. I realise I could use multiple 'if' statements but what is the point in doing that when the 'select' functionality was designed to remove the need for overly complex and long winded 'if' statements?

Comment: @Cameron - The `select` expression is designed to find the first case statement that matches the condition.  It isn't designed to evaluate *all* case statements.