# crystal report group on multiple criteria

Tags: crystal-reports

This is a strange scenario that I'm having trouble working out:

I have a report that needs to show the summary of donations that each board member gave/got in any fiscal year. They get credit for hard credit donations, soft credit donations, and solicited donations. Meaning their record ID number is in 3 columns throughout the spreadsheet.

So, my data looks like this:

Soft Credit ID/Hard Credit ID/Solicitor ID/Gift Amount

1/-/-/$50

-/1/-/$100

-/-/1/$250

I need to be able to group these records together because they each have the ID # "1" in the record (but in a different column each time). I need to group these records together, so that it shows the summary for each board member, with the details below:

Board member ID 1: Total Giving $400

Soft credit - $50 - 4/1/13

Hard Credit - $100 - 3/29/13

Solicitor Credit - $250 - 7/2/13
(^These don't need to be summaries, this just needs to list all gifts and which kind of credit they give)

I'm having trouble because I don't see a way to group based on the ID, in different fields. I tried grouping based on a formula for each board member (formula read {Hard Credit ID}="1" OR {Soft credit ID}="1" OR {solicitor credit}="1") but it didn't work and it creates a hierarchy that I'm not looking for. Apologies for the formatting - I can't find instructions on how to make that block above appear as a table.

Answer (score 0):

Replace nulls in the three fields with 0 and then concatenate.  You will then have a possibility of three values in the new field: 100 010 001

If you concatenate the three ID fields into a new field without replacing the nulls then you will get "1", "1" and "1".  If you replace the nulls with 0, then you will get "100", "010", and "001".  Now, you can group-by on the new field and you will get subtotals, or skip-group-by and just list the detail.  To extract the description of the code, if we are only talking about 3 possible values, you can use nested `if` statements to examine first value and test if it equal to "100", else test if equal to "010", else test if equal to "001", else error.  Or a `case` statement, syntax examples here: [Select/Case in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941680/select-case-in-crystal-reports) or [Crystal Reports SELECT CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525420/crystal-reports-select-case-statement?rq=1)

Comment: I'm not sure if that will solve my problem. I am working with an .mdb file exported from my database, so I don't think I can replace the nulls with 0's, but if I was able to, I still am not sure how to get my desired outcome.

Comment: Crystal has an option in the Formula Editor to do "Exception for Nulls" which is default, or you can change it to "Default Values for Nulls" which is what (I think) user3038209 is suggesting. This approach still won't solve your problem, though, because each type of credit will still appear in a different group for the same board member.

Comment: Concatenating the three fields into one field should solve the problem as intruesiive will still be able to calculate a total and then _also_ a subtotal(by grouping by the concatenation).  intruesiive - if you have modification privleges of the .mdb you could do the concatenation there...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, depending on your source DB, is to use a SQL Expression to condense the three fields:

`coalesce({table.SoftCreditID},{table.HardCreditID},{table.SolicitorID})`

Or you can do it in a regular formula:

```
if not(isnull({table.SoftCreditID)) then {table.SoftCreditID}
else if not(isnull({table.HardCreditID})) then {table.HardCreditID}
else {table.SolicitorID}
```